# Create a bookshelf relation model with multiple joins

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

Is it possible to create a Bookshelf relation model that spans multiple tables?

For instance, given the following structure:

```
    Table "public.foo"
    Column      |     Type                               
----------------+---------------
      id        |    integer     

    Table "public.bar"
    Column      |     Type                               
----------------+---------------
      id        |    integer   
    foo_id      |    integer

    Table "public.baz"
    Column      |     Type                               
----------------+---------------
      id        |    integer    
    bar_id      |    integer

    Table "public.wibble"
    Column      |     Type                               
----------------+---------------
      id        |    integer     
    baz_id      |    integer
   wobble_id    |    integer

    Table "public.wobble"
    Column      |     Type                               
----------------+---------------
      id        |    integer
```

I want to load the `foo` collection on an instance of `wobble` (`wobble` is related to `foo` via `wibble`->`baz`->`bar`->`foo`).

Comment: Please clarity what this has to do with book shelves and what you mean by relation model (graph? normalised entity relation model? ...)

Comment: He's referring to the bookshelf.js ORM for node. Bookshelf uses an object called a relation that provides a specific API surface to fetching related models from the DB. This differs from their standard collection. The terms are so overloaded in this context it's hard to keep them all straight, but he's referring to the names of the objects in that library, not in their more general usage.